# La comunicación entre JavaScript y Android no funciona

Tags: javascript, android

Trato de que al momento de dar clic a un botón en una página de un *WebView* me mande una alerta con *Android*. Ya he intentado de todo y ni *Android* ni *PHP* me mandan ningún error.

Código Activity Principal:

```
this.webv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webv.getSettings();
webv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webv.loadUrl("http://192.168.137.1/walletgo/");
webv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

Código *Webappinterface* donde tengo el método que se ejecuta:

```
public class WebAppInterface
{
    Context context;

    public WebAppInterface(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showDialog(String message) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
        builder.setMessage(message).setNeutralButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        );
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

Botón en *PHP*:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello!" onclick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(message){ Android.showDialog(message); }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey espera el botón que indicas esta en la url  http://192.168.137.1/walletgo/ ??? @SidneyFlores

Comment: Si, esta en una pagina php dentro de ese proyecto

Comment: revisa lo que comento en mi respuesta. @SidneyFlores , revisaste el LogCat y no se muestra en verdad ningún mensaje?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tratas de realizar es una interfaz Javascript para comunicarte por medio de Javascritpt con la aplicación, [JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html) ...

No aparenta tener algún problema la creación de la interfaz

```
this.webv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webv.getSettings();
webv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //Habilitar Javascript
webv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
webv.loadUrl("http://192.168.137.1/walletgo/");
```

pero el método `showDialog()` que es llamado desde tu página crea un dialogo, **debes asegurar que el contexto que usa el dialogo para crearse, sea el de la Activity**, si no no se mostrará. Si la clase interfaz esta declarada en la misma `Activity`, usa únicamente `this` como contexto:

también agrega un mensaje para que verifiques el método se esta ejecutando correctamente.

```
  @JavascriptInterface
    public void showDialog(String message) {

        Log.i("showDialog", "El método se llama con el mensaje: " + message);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setNeutralButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        );
        builder.create().show();
    }
```

Ejemplo usando usando una JavascriptInterface mostrando como realizar la comunicación desde una página web a una aplicación android:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Javascriptinterface

Answer (score 0):

A mí sí, me funcionó el código, creo que lo que hace falta es habilitar *Javascript*.

```
WebView web1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web1.loadUrl("http://XXX.XX.X.XX/paginas/pagina.html");
web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
web1.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```