# Al girar pantalla se cierra la sesión en Webview

Tags: android, webview-android

Tengo un `webview` en Android con una dirección a una pagina web responsiva en **`PHP`**, en general, todo funciona bien, pero cuando giro la pantalla, se me lleva al login nuevamente, ¿por qué?

Comment: Si deseas desarrollar en Android, el uso del LogCat es importante para que no pierdas tiempo en buscar cual es el error, en ocasiones puede ser una infinidad de razones, te recomiendo agregues el error desplegado en el LogCat.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de "solucionar" los issues relacionados con rotación es definir en el AndroidManifest.xml para la Activity que contiene el WebView, la propiedad :

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

ejemplo:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityConWebView"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Pero es importante saber cual es error que causa este problema porque en ocasiones se requiere acceso al método `onCreate()` de la `Activity` al girar el dispositivo.

Comment: Entonces seria como un parche ese código? Gracias, luego lo pruebo

Comment: he buscado para contactarte y hacerte una pregunta, pero no encontré la opción en este foro.

Comment: Que tal que pregunta tienes? :)

Comment: en realidad necesito hacer que desde mi webview se puedan adjuntar archivos (seleccionar algún archivo de la carpeta y/o usar la cámara), estuve viendo como era y excede mis limites, por ende, si lo podemos arreglarlo como un trabajo y me decís cuanto $$

Comment: No te preocupes te ayudo pero en ese caso necesitas una JacascriptInterface, revisa la respuesta y el ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40753/la-comunicación-entre-javascript-y-android-no-funciona/40759#40759

Comment: pero eso es para mostrar un dialogo, yo necesito que se abra una ventana que te permita elegir archivos del móvil, podríamos hablarlo por privado?

Comment: por favor, me puedes dar una mano?. Como mencione antes eso es para un Toast.

Comment: Hola acabo de ver tu mensaje, esto en reaĺidad es para una activity. La ventana que deseas abrir es es un WebView? O un dialogo

Comment: Tengo un webview!!, pero un formulario de mi WEB requiere seleccionar un archivo, es decir, mi aplicación funciona perfecta MENOS en esa parte porque cuando presiono sobre "subir foto" no se abre nada. Necesito crear un código que permita seleccionar un archivo del móvil, me explico? puedo pasar mi correo por aquí o no se puede?