# Error en mi form con un webview?

Tags: php, javascript, android, html, html5

que error pueden ver aquí?. Ya que en los navegadores funciona bien la carga de archivos, pero cuando uso un webview (probado con otra web de testeo y que funciona bien) en mi web no funciona, por ende, todo indica que a mi form algo le falta.

Necesito que sea compatible con la mayor cantidad de versiones posibles y si se trata de 4.4.2 muestre un mensaje (un Toast o algo diciendo que no es compatible), en caso de que no exista tal posibilidad, me interesa mas que sea compatible para versiones iguales o superiores a la 5.0 .

Desde ya muchas gracias.
Aquí el code: (uso materialize css)

```
<form method="POST" class="col s12 m12 l12 offset-l0 m0 s0 white blue-text" name="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!-- Tamano del form responsive, color de texto y de fondo-->  
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12"> <!-- Tamano del input-field Titulo-->
                                <i class="material-icons prefix">report_problem</i>
                                <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate" name="txtNombre">
                                <label for="icon_prefix">Titulo</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <div class="row">   
                <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12"> <!-- Tamano del input-field Descripcion-->
                                <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
                                <textarea id="icon_prefix2" class="materialize-textarea" name="txtDescripcion" value="0/500"></textarea>
                                <label for="icon_prefix2">Descripcion</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                <div class="row">
                             <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12"> <!-- Tamano del input-field Upload-File-->
                                 <div class="file-field input-field">
                                    <div class="btn blue">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
                                        <span>Archivo</span>
                                        <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen">
                                    </div>
                                  <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                                    <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, DOC, XLS, DOCX, PPT, XLSX">
                                  </div>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                </div>

                     <div class="row">
                       <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12 center"> <!-- Tamano del boton enviar-->
                                  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue" type="submit" name="action">Enviar
                                  <i class="material-icons right">send</i></button>
                               </div>
                            </div>


                    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un problema conocido para los webview de Android. Necesitas implementar la lógica de subida de ficheros para el webview. Te paso una solución que funciona muy bien planchada descaradamente de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15423907/3382947):

```
public class MyWb extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

WebView web;
ProgressBar progressBar;

private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;  
 private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;  

 @Override  
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                    Intent intent) {  
  if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
  {  
   if (null == mUploadMessage) return;  
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null  
                    : intent.getData();  
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);  
            mUploadMessage = null;  
  }
  }  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    web = new WebView(this);  
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/199/index.html");
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()  
    {  
           //The undocumented magic method override  
           //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here  
        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
            i.setType("image/*");  
            MyWb.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);  

           }

        // For Android 3.0+
           public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
           mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
           i.setType("*/*");
           MyWb.this.startActivityForResult(
           Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
           FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
           }

        //For Android 4.1
           public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
               mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
               i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
               i.setType("image/*");  
               MyWb.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), MyWb.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

           }

    });  


    setContentView(web);  


}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

//flipscreen not loading again
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
/*@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}*/
}
```

---

### EDITADO:

Según lo que hemos hablado en el chat, te paso el código de un activity con un caso de uso completo para más versiones de Android y con soporte para el acceso a la cámara del dispositivo también.

Espero que lo encuentres de utilidad:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class WebActivity extends Activity {
    //region WebView vars
    private WebView wv;
    private WebSettings webSettings;
    //endregion
    //region File Chooser vars
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;
    //endregion

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

        wv.loadUrl("http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/199/index.html");

        WebSettings wv_settings = wv.getSettings();
        wv_settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv_settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        wv_settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv_settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        wv_settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv_settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        wv_settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        wv_settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        wv.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebClient());
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient());

        wv.clearCache(true);
    }


    //region File Selection Helpers
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        return imageFile;
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }
            Uri[] results = null;
            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }
            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }
                Uri result = null;
                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        result = null;
                    } else {
                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    //endregion

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wv.canGoBack()) {
            wv.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public class CustomWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }

        //region File Chooser
        // For Android 5.0
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePath;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Selector de imagen");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        }
        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    , "AndroidExampleFolder");
            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(
                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Selector de imagen");
            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                    , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });
            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }
        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }
        //endregion File Chooser
    }

    public class CustomWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // If url contains mailto link then open Mail Intent
            if (url.contains("mailto:")) {
                // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                //Open links in new browser
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                // Here we can open new activity
                return true;
            }else {
                // Stay within this webview and load url
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
        //Show loader on url load
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // Then show progress  Dialog
            // in standard case YourActivity.this
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        // Called when all page resources loaded
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                // Close progressDialog
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Un trillon de gracias, aunque creo haber probado ese código y funciona perfectamente con la web de testeo que has incluido, pero con mi web no funciona, por lo que llegado a pensar que me falta algo (no se si Javascript, o algo del form, o X cosa.)

Comment: @Strelok en principio no, tampoco he visto nada incorrecto en el formulario que nos proporcionaste (aunque se me ha podido pasar algo). Yo mismo me encontré con ese problema en alguna ocasión y la solución residía en implementar la lógica del tratamiento de ficheros en el webview que por defecto no viene implementada. Ocurre algo concreto o simplemente no muestra nada? Podrías intentar a depurar este código línea a línea a ver si algún evento no se está lanzando al pulsar en el `input[file]`?

Comment: Mucha gracias por tu respuesta, pues simplemente cuando presiono sobre "subir archivo" estando en el webview, no sucede nada. Por lo que llegue a pensar que falta algo de javascript o algo que le diga al webview que tiene que abrir el album para seleccionar un archivo.

Comment: Prueba lo que te comento. Establece unos puntos de interrupción (y/o trazas de log) en los métodos de `openFileChooser` y mira a ver si se están lanzando. Si no se están lanzando algo no está funcionando bien y si tuviera que apostar, diría que el problema está en el código `Android`. Si ves que no se lanza, edita la respuesta para poner el código `Android` correspondiente (y dinos cual es la versión de la SDK por si acaso también) y miramos a ver si vemos algún problema por ahí ;)

Comment: Vale, voy a intentarlo y te comento en 10 minutos. No te vayas por favor, hace 1 mes que estoy con este problema jajajja

Comment: Lo acabo de probar con BLUESTACK y no funciona ;/ es desesperante

Comment: En Jelly me ha funcionado, pero materialize css no funciona jaja! se ve horrible. Que versión mínima me recomiendas?

Comment: D/GLWebViewState: Reinit transferQueue

                  [ 12-31 19:03:36.990  1595: 1868 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7f12888, tid 1868
E/Web Console: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at http://MyPage.com/materialize/js/materialize.min.js:6

Comment: @Strelok Me alegro que al final en Jelly te haya funcionado ;) Una lástima lo del materialize (aunque para eso igual mejor crear otra pregunta, si esta la damos por finalizada). Por el error que me comentas me parece que el jQuery no se ha cargado correctamente y materialize lo tiene como dependencia. Pero como digo eso igual mejor para otra pregunta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57965/discussion-between-strelok-and-frikinside).

Comment: me gustaría charlar un momento contigo en el chat. ya entro

Comment: Lo he probado en mi móvil (5.1) y anda perfecto y materialize css también, como agradecerte :( ?. Solo tengo 1 problema y una duda. El problema lo describí aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61361/al-girar-pantalla-se-cierra-la-sesi%C3%B3n-en-webview/61366?noredirect=1#comment117046_61366  y la duda es si el color rosa de la barra de carga se puede reemplazar fácilmente? Nuevamente mil gracias :D

Comment: Nada, me alegro que te haya funcionado, el único modo de agradecerme y no a mi, si no a la comunidad (si no hubiera sido yo, hubiera sido otro) es marcar esta respuesta como aceptada, para que las consultas de otros usuarios tengan la certeza de que el código funciona y soluciona el problema, cuando tenga un rato, reviso la otra pregunta a ver si te puedo ayudar ;)